# SMTP Gives error :- Mailbox unavailable. The server response was: Access denied - Invalid HELO name (See RFC2821 4.1.1.1)

Tags: c#, asp.net, smtp, windows-services, smtpexception

I'm running an aspx application on a remote machine which runs a service that is responsible for sending out emails via SMTP. It is unable to send emails and gives me the following error

Exception type:       System.Net.Mail.SmtpException
Exception message:    Mailbox unavailable. The server response was: Access denied - Invalid HELO name (See RFC2821 4.1.1.1)

On the contrary I created a console application on the same remote machine and wrote a simple program to send email via the same SMTP details and it works fine, the following is its working code

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        MailAddress to = new MailAddress("*********");

        MailAddress from = new MailAddress("******"); // Note :- from and user inside N/w Credentails is same


        MailMessage mail = new MailMessage(from, to);
       
        mail.Subject = "TESTING PLEASE IGNORE";
        
        mail.Body = "TESTING MAIL BODY";

        SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();
        smtp.Host = "*********";
        smtp.Port = 587;

        smtp.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(
            "********", "**********");
        smtp.EnableSsl = true;
        Console.WriteLine("Sending email...");
        smtp.Send(mail);

    }
}
```

This is the application code which doesn't work.

```
string id = "";
        string cc = "";
        string bcc = "";
        string to = "";
        MailMessage objMailMessage = new MailMessage();
        
        SmtpClient SmtpMail = new SmtpClient();
        SmtpMail.Host = "****"; 
        
        SmtpMail.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("*********", "*************"); 
        SmtpMail.EnableSsl = true; 
        
        SmtpMail.Port = 587; 
        if (req != null)
        {
            Log("External email request queued internally: " + req.OuterXml);
            try
            {
                id = req.SelectSingleNode("/QuotationServer/EmailRequest").Attributes["id"].Value;
                to = req.SelectSingleNode("/QuotationServer/EmailRequest").Attributes["to"].Value;
                cc = req.SelectSingleNode("/QuotationServer/EmailRequest").Attributes["cc"].Value;
                bcc = req.SelectSingleNode("/QuotationServer/EmailRequest").Attributes["bcc"].Value;
        
                string from = "*********************";
                string subject = req.SelectSingleNode("/QuotationServer/EmailRequest").Attributes["subject"].Value;
                string body = req.SelectSingleNode("/QuotationServer/EmailRequest").Attributes["body"].Value;
        
                objMailMessage.To.Add(new MailAddress(to.Replace(";",",")));

                if (cc.Trim() != "")
                {
                    objMailMessage.CC.Add(new MailAddress(cc.Replace(";", ",")));
                }
                if (bcc.Trim() != "")
                {
                    objMailMessage.Bcc.Add(new MailAddress(bcc.Replace(";", ",")));
                }
                objMailMessage.From = new MailAddress(from);
                objMailMessage.Subject = subject;
                objMailMessage.Body = body;
        


                if (req.SelectSingleNode("/QuotationServer/EmailRequest/Attachment").Attributes["path"] != null)
                {
                    string pdffile = req.SelectSingleNode("/QuotationServer/EmailRequest/Attachment").Attributes["path"].Value.ToString();
                    objMailMessage.Attachments.Add(new System.Net.Mail.Attachment(pdffile));
                }

                Log("server name: " + m_SMTPServer + ", password: " + m_SMTPpassword + ", user and port: " + m_SMTPuser + ", " + m_SMTPport + "");

               

                SmtpMail.Send(objMailMessage);
                }
                }
```

I tried changing SMTP settings enabling SSL setting default credentials to false etc nothing works.

What might be the issue ?

Edit (26/10/2023)

The issue seems to be of the .Net Framework Version

It runs fine on 4.6.1 but for some reason not on 2.0 ?

Comment: Hi! Try posting the code that you're using (confidential info removed of course) so that we can analyze it better instead of images. It helps us help you!

Comment: Just did that have a look. @Ars_Codicis

Comment: Are they the exact same hostname and port? Side note: for muliple addresses you need to split by `;` or `,` and add them separately?

Comment: The domain of the host may not be correct : https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc2821#section-4.1.1.1  Is the Host a name or IP.  If IP is it IPV4 or IPV6?

Comment: Yes the hostname and port are exactly same and it is a single address @Charlieface

Comment: Host is a name not an IP address. @jdweng

Comment: From cmd.exe can you ping the hostname?

Comment: Get Credentials has a domain property : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.networkcredential.domain?view=net-7.0

Comment: Just tried adding a blank domain property in N/w Credentials, doesn't work and I'm prohibited to share hostname.
Maybe something to with windows service ?
 @jdweng

Comment: There is a permission issue.   You corporate Network is using Group Policy.  The local machine login and the remote machine aren't using the same server for password validation.  Either one of two things may be happening.  With email it uses port forwarding where all the SMTP ports are forwarded by firewall to an Email Proxy Server.  The credentials are failing at the Proxy.  Could be the domains of local machine and SMTP are different.  Or the FROM address of email is not matching the Credentials.  Simple solution is to correct the FROM ADDRESS to the SMTP object.

Comment: Seen issue also when going between a unix/linux machine to a Window email server.  Then you may need to setup a relay.  If you are inside a corporate network you may not need to use a secure port 587 and instead use a non secure port 25.

Comment: But I ran a console application to send email with same credentials on the same remote it worked.
Also the application today was able to send the email just once successfully and then never again 
@jdweng

Comment: Also tried with port 25 @jdweng

Comment: In c# you must use "SmtpClient SmtpMail = new SmtpClient();" every time a new email it sent.  You can't loop on same client, it must be a new instance.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your aspx web server’s hostName is invalid when used by the SmtpClient for sending the HELO command.

This has nothing to do with SSL settings, the Mail server’s hostName, or any of the From/To/Cc addresses.

System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient is getting some invalid hostName string for the machine your code is running on or it resolved it to an internal IP address which is not exposed to the Mail server’s network, thereby making it so that your Mail server can’t rDNS it and so it responds with an error to the HELO command.

If you write a test app using MailKit to send a simple email, you can get a protocol log to see what host name your app thinks it is running on by examining the log to see what is sent in the HELO command.

Or you can just rewrite your app to use MailKit to send email and override MailKit’s SmtpClient.LocalDomain property to set it to something valid.